# Sound Cloud custom player - "id property is null" error

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

I'm having some issues working with the Sound Cloud custom html5 player (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player) specifically on internet explorer (tested on version 7, 8 and 9).

It seems whenever the player is created (right now this is dynamically through JS) it is running into an error with a function in the "sc-player.js" file (provided by sound cloud [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/archives/master)).

The error is "Unable to get the value or property 'id': object null or undefined". This is the code that messes up: line 640 character 9

```
 // selecting tracks in the playlist
  $('.sc-trackslist li').live('click', function(event) {
var $track = $(this),
    $player = $track.closest('.sc-player'),
    trackId = $track.data('sc-track').id,
    play = $player.is(':not(.playing)') || $track.is(':not(.active)');
if (play) {
  onPlay($player, trackId);
}else{
  onPause($player);
}
$track.addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
$('.artworks li', $player).each(function(index) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active', index === trackId);
});
return false;
});
```

I understand this is trying to find the id of a track on the generated list, however I have hidden this list on the page, so really shouldn't that click event should not even fire? I have tried removing the click event all together but that seems to cause a number of other issues with the player.

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced this or knows how to get around it?

EDIT -

I manually attached "test" data the track. And this seems to solve that first error, but of course brings up another. This time the same error is spat out for this line (in the sc-player.js file):

```
getPlayerData = function(node) {
   return players[$(node).data('sc-player').id];
}
```

This is the code **I use** to call the player, the track argument being the link to a music tracks soundcloud page, and #player being the empty div its being created on top of:

```
function init_player(track,title) {
  $('.open #player').scPlayer({
   links: [{url: track, title: title}],
   beforeRender  :   function(tracksData) {
      $scplayer = $(this);
      $('.sc-trackslist li, .sc-trackslist li a').data({ id: track});
  }
}
```

When the user wants to change to another section of music, I then have another function which empties the container div, appends #player to it (because it was overwritten by the soundcloud player), and re runs the above function.

My issue is on the second time the init_player function is run, I get the error.

Sorry for the delayed response!

Comment: Alon is right, the error is here: `trackId = $track.data('sc-track').id`. Can you ensure that element has an attribute `data-sc-track`?

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
trackId = $track.data('sc-track').id,
```

I can't help you more then that because I need the rest of the code...